# c# brackets statement after semaphore.Wait() without condition or header

Tags: c#, syntax, semaphore

I came across the following code in c#:

```
        semaphore.Wait();
        {
            HandleRateLimit(region);
        }
        semaphore.Release();
```

([source](https://github.com/BenFradet/RiotSharp/blob/a663c4e32d8931adb376e3eda7a2eb1bcecb614e/RiotSharp/RateLimitedRequester.cs#L35))

I was wondering, do the brackets around the `HandleRateLimit(...)` call have any special meaning? If not, why would someone write code that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets have nothing to do with semaphores. The idea was, probably, to make it more readable and to point out critical section.